# spring-integration: Error handling on inbound adapters

Tags: spring-integration

Basics:

- Using spring 4.1.1 with integration, boot and 1.0.0 of the DSL.
- Multiple inbound SFTP adapters on different schedules fetching files from different vendors.
- Each integration flow attaches headers to the message after the files are downloaded to identify the vendor source.
- Use a MessagePublishingErrorHandler to handle exceptions.
- Standard message flow notify an external monitoring solution when a message is successfully processed or when a message fails to complete.  Uses the message headers to identify which flow failed.

Both the success and error flows work great, after we have a message.  However, when we encounter an error that occurs before a message is produced (i.e. could not connect to sftp server), we don't have a chance to attach the headers.

I've been looking at the samples and documentation, and I cannot find a good way to attach the same headers from the error message produced by the MessagePublishingErrorHandler without overriding the error handler on the Poller, or creating a custom error flow for every inbound integration.  What options do I have here?

This is an example of one of the configs:

```
        IntegrationFlows
        .from(
            Sftp.inboundAdapter(sessionFactory)
                    .autoCreateLocalDirectory(true)
                    .localDirectory(configProperties.getLocalDirectory())
                    .preserveTimestamp(true)
                    .remoteDirectory(configProperties.getRemoteDirectory()),
            c -> c.poller(Pollers
                    .fixedRate(properties.getSftpInterval(), properties.getSftpIntervalUnit())
                    .errorHandler(errorHandler)) // custom error handler?
        )
        .enrichHeaders(
                    MapBuilder
                            .with("vendorName", "vendor1")
                            .get()
        )
        .channel("fileChannelHandler")
        .get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah - the problem is that, with polled channel adapters, if an exception is thrown in the `MessageSource.receive()`, there's not yet any message to enhance with custom headers.

The framework currently doesn't allow modifying the headers of the `ErrorMessage` itself (which has the raw exception as its payload for exceptions like this).

One work-around (aside from your custom EH) would be to put a header enricher on each error-flow to identify the source adapter.

In future, the framework could add a header to the ErrorMessage, containing the id of the channel adapter so the source can be identified in a common error flow.

Feel free to open an 'Improvement' [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT) and we'll take a look.

Comment: I also had the same issue with no ability to enrich headers in errorhandlers . Will be great if we had the same ability comparable to Camel's central exchange provides to also capture certain business information onFailure .